# How to provision OOTB CTs (Audio, Video and Image) to Custom WebTemplate

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, content-type, web-template

I want to provision Out of the Box CTs Audio, Video and Image to my Custom Web Template which is based on "BDR#0" in SharePoint 2013. How i do this ? Should i need to provision some feature to my custom web Template to accomplish this ? if yes, then what is the Id of that feature ?

Comment: What do you mean with "Add them to the webtemplate"? Do you want them on some library or what?

Comment: i modified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be provisoned by default. Here is a guide of how to add them to a list http://sharepointontop.blogspot.se/2012/09/sharepoint-2013-videoaudio-content-types.html

They are part of Publishing in SharePoint, so make sure publishing is enabled.

The Content types are automatically available in Asset Libraries. So if you create an asset library, it will be preconfigured: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/set-up-an-asset-library-to-store-image-audio-or-video-files-HA102785730.aspx

To active Publishing in your WebTemplate:
Site Scoped features:

```
<!-- Publishing Site-->
<Feature ID="f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa" />

<!-- PublishingPrerequisites -->
<Feature ID="A392DA98-270B-4e85-9769-04C0FDE267AA" />
```

Web Scoped features:

```
<!--Publishing feature-->
        <Feature ID="22A9EF51-737B-4ff2-9346-694633FE4416">
          <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
            <Property Key="ChromeMasterUrl" Value=""/>
            <Property Key="WelcomePageUrl" Value="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;/default.aspx"/>
            <Property Key="PagesListUrl" Value=""/>
            <Property Key="AvailableWebTemplates" Value=""/>
            <Property Key="AvailablePageLayouts" Value=""/>
            <Property Key="SimplePublishing" Value="true" />
            <Property Key="DefaultPageLayout" Value=""/>
          </Properties>
        </Feature>

    <Feature ID="541F5F57-C847-4e16-B59A-B31E90E6F9EA">
      <!-- Per-Web Portal Navigation Properties-->
      <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
        <Property Value="true" Key="InheritGlobalNavigation"/>
        <Property Value="true" Key="IncludeSubSites"/>
        <Property Value="true" Key="IncludePages"/>
      </Properties>
    </Feature>
```

Comment: Ok!, But i want to auto activate "SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure feature" by provisioning it through my custom web template. So, whats the id of this feature ?

Comment: Updated wit hthe features you need

Comment: Thanks, It works.But when i activate Publishing feature provisioned through my web template, My custom libraries are not showing on QuickLaunch bar. When i deactivate the feature, my document libraries are visible again on QuickLaunch bar. Can you explain, why its happening ?

Comment: Try setting the property InheritCurrentNavigation to true or false, like I have under InheritGLobalNavigation. Just add a similar property but for InheritCurrentNavigation

Comment: Hi again, I have added InheritCurrentNavigation property and set its value to true, but no success. Then i set property to false and deployed and check again, still it doesn't show libraries on QuickLaunch bar? any idea ?

Comment: Please add this as a seperate question or google it, the are tons of information regarding navigation and publishing'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9072/discussion-between-spbeginer-and-robert-lindgren)