# How to change the page layout of the default page in share point 2013?

Tags: 2013

I found this blog for 2010

http://blogbaris.blogspot.be/2010/11/setting-default-page-layout-in-onetxml.html

I am trying to do it for 2013

it seems obvious the page layout has to be in the master page gallery

However, I dont know in which publishing feature should I put those properties

in the site collection publishing infrastructure feature? or in the website publishing feauture

```
<Configurations>
    <Configuration ID="1" Name="Blank" MasterUrl="_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master">
      <Lists />
      <Modules>
        <Module Name="DefaultBlank" />
      </Modules>
      <SiteFeatures>
        <!-- PublishingPrerequisites -->
        <Feature ID="A392DA98-270B-4e85-9769-04C0FDE267AA" />

        <!--Document ID Service-->
        <Feature ID="b50e3104-6812-424f-a011-cc90e6327318" />
        <!--SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure-->
        <Feature ID="f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa" />
        <!-- Document Set -->
        <Feature ID="3bae86a2-776d-499d-9db8-fa4cdc7884f8" />
        <!--Managed Metadata-->
        <!--???-->
        <!--[CUSTOM] Site Columns Base-->
        <Feature ID="04009fbe-bd55-4217-b400-7264e1985e04" />
        <!--[CUSTOM] Site Columns Clients-->
        <Feature ID="6f826126-27d5-49da-9c57-37b3ecebbd90" />
        <!--[CUSTOM] Content Types Base-->
        <Feature ID="f8fd0e77-45fd-4de1-84b1-e60c044ff09c" />
        <!--[CUSTOM] Content Types Clients-->
        <Feature ID="9047bc67-bf2a-48e6-85a7-4e8269a0735a" />
        <!--[CUSTOM] Content Types System-->
        <Feature ID="fa5c018a-58c1-419d-aa1c-22d5b3a629b8" />

        <!-- job and opportunity sites can be sub sites for this site collection. -->
        <!--[CUSTOM] Web template: Opportunity Site-->
        <Feature ID="f9670c61-1eea-4544-8458-da87a96a77b9" />
        <!--[CUSTOM] Web template: Job Site-->
        <Feature ID="79f06e9e-24cc-4804-9014-49092ee6c733" />



      </SiteFeatures>
      <WebFeatures>
        <!-- SharePoint Server Publishing -->
        <Feature ID="94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb"/>

        <!-- SharePoint Server Publishing http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70018/how-to-change-the-page-layout-of-the-default-page-in-share-point-2013 -->
        <Feature ID="22A9EF51-737B-4ff2-9346-694633FE4416" >
          <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
            <Property Key="ChromeMasterUrl" Value=""/>
            <Property Key="WelcomePageUrl" Value="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;/default.aspx"/>
            <Property Key="PagesListUrl" Value=""/>
            <Property Key="AvailableWebTemplates" Value=""/>
            <Property Key="AvailablePageLayouts" Value=""/>
            <Property Key="SimplePublishing" Value="true" />
            <Property Key="DefaultPageLayout" value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/BlankWebPartPage.aspx" />
          </Properties>
        </Feature>

        <!-- Metadata Navigation and Filtering -->
        <Feature ID="7201d6a4-a5d3-49a1-8c19-19c4bac6e668" />
        <!-- Following Content -->
        <Feature ID="a7a2793e-67cd-4dc1-9fd0-43f61581207a"/>
        <!-- Site Feed -->
        <Feature ID="15a572c6-e545-4d32-897a-bab6f5846e18" />

        <!--[CUSTOM] List Client Info -->
        <Feature ID="0cf1b189-4233-407c-a9b3-099d8ec94e75" />
        <!--[CUSTOM] Library Client Invoices-->
        <Feature ID="d54fc17e-405a-4d74-a661-9d4bb3d1b9ad" />
        <!--[CUSTOM] Library Client Correspondence -->
        <Feature ID="844df276-bb50-48bb-bf02-c165443085b0" />
        <!--[CUSTOM] Library Client Risk Management -->
        <Feature ID="73d0c077-44f9-48fc-9891-211563fe165c" />
        <!--[CUSTOM] Library Client Other documents -->
        <Feature ID="9a439920-ab55-4623-b875-986541154906" />

        <!--[CUSTOM] Navigation Top-->
        <Feature ID="987d3b74-1381-4d5a-a5d8-47b4cb126bc4"/>

        <!--[CUSTOM] Client Site Web Properties -->
        <Feature ID="1492e97a-3017-4b62-8c12-e140f5eaca25" />        


      </WebFeatures>
    </Configuration>
  </Configurations>
  <Modules>
    <Module Name="DefaultBlank" Url="" Path="">
      <File Url="default.aspx" NavBarHome="True" Type="Ghostable" >
        <Property Key="PublishingPageLayout" value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/BlankWebPartPage.aspx, Blank Web Part Page" />
        <NavBarPage Name="~siteTitle" Url="~site" ID="1002" Position="Start" />
        <NavBarPage Name="~siteTitle" Url="" ID="0" Position="Start" />
```

**Update:**

If I comment the property in the module, then it doesnt throw the exception. and the site is created, however when I uncomment the property from the file, it throws the same exception.

```
<Property Key="PublishingPageLayout" value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/BlankWebPartPage.aspx, Blank Web Part Page" />


System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId)
```

Comment: Are you doing this in a Site Definition? Seems a bit old school

Comment: in onet.xml, how else?

Comment: OK, so it is an ONET for Site Definition, not Web Template? Since you have your module in the Onet itself?

Comment: Any how, you still need to activate more features (as you can see from the error message in your other post you are missing feature dependencies). Please try to add all for features from the first link in my answer to solve both of your problems.

Comment: please see the edited code and the update

Comment: As I said, you are getting the error because you are passing in Properties to the wrong feature.

Comment: are you sure its the same feature id for 2013? maybe it changed?  maybe your solution works for 2010?

Comment: Well I have only made about 15 publishing WebTemplates for 2013, so what so I know.. I'm out

Comment: lol, I am trying now, I didnt make this current web template, and I dont know why they used that id

Comment: do I need the per portal navigation feature? Per-Web Portal Navigation Properties feature?

Comment: @RobertLindgren please see my updated code, I pasted almost all onet.xml, it looks identical to your, still have the exception

Comment: AFAIK, Blank WebPartPage is not a publishing page layout, and you are not even uploading your page to the pages library (the url for the module is not set), and Type should be Ghostable in Library for publishing pages. Your default page is a normal page, not a publishing page. And also, if this is a WebTemplate, as opposed to a Site Definition, you can not add modules in the onet itself!

Comment: And regarding the Per portal navigation, no you can leave them out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69630/how-to-provision-ootb-cts-audio-video-and-image-to-custom-webtemplate/69652#69652) for complete publishing features, both site and web scoped.

You should add this as a web scoped feature:

```
        <!--Publishing feature-->
        <Feature ID="22A9EF51-737B-4ff2-9346-694633FE4416">
          <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
            <Property Key="ChromeMasterUrl" Value=""/>
            <Property Key="WelcomePageUrl" Value="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;/default.aspx"/>
            <Property Key="PagesListUrl" Value=""/>
            <Property Key="AvailableWebTemplates" Value=""/>
            <Property Key="AvailablePageLayouts" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/MyLayout.aspx:~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/SomeOtherLayout.aspx"/>
            <Property Key="SimplePublishing" Value="true" />
            <Property Key="DefaultPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/MyLayout.aspx"/>
          </Properties>
        </Feature>
```

As you can see you can change a lot of thing, including the default and available Page Layouts, aswell

[This post by Vesa](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2007/10/14/controlling-publishing-features-from-onet-xml.aspx) is still very valid when it comes to working with publishing features in WebT emplates or Site Templates. Here you can see the format for some of the other properties

Comment: I am confused with the feature id, Isnt it 94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb?

Comment: I use the for features in my first link (2 site scoped, 2 web scoped). For changing these things you need to add the properties to the 22A9... one)

Comment: pls see my edited code.